# Jquery Focusing on div to apply CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus

I have various styles, such as:

```
.line{}
```

And:

```
.line:focus{}
```

Each have their own unique look.

What I want to do is have jquery focus on a div with the `.line` class and thus change it's style to `line:focus`. However, when using `$('.line').focus();`, the style does not change, and I'm reasonably sure the div with .line class is not focused on.

Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks in advance :).

Comment: If you're going to use JS to apply the styles, you'd be better off not using the pseudoclass and applying the style directyl

Comment: I would, however I cannot use rgba() and animate to that style. I was hoping to use css transitions.

Comment: No, I meant apply the style directly. `.line_focus` would contain all the styles you need. Just apply the class when you want to focus on it

Comment: @JohnP, yes, but I'm using rgba(); in my background:; css styles and using jQuery to switch/animate between styles will not work when using rgba();. Hence my wanting to use :focus so that css would do the transition animation.

Comment: hmm, I'm not too good with the CSS stuff. Since you're getting similar answers below, maybe it would help if you setup a demo on jsfiddle and added it to the question.

Comment: That might be an idea. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) would work, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GvxgP/)

---

Edit:

Without a focus-able element, I would use toggleClass [**demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GvxgP/4/)

Comment: I'm trying to focus on a div, not an input. It works fine for inputs. I'm guessing it's not possible to focus on a div?

Comment: That would be good, however I cannot have users editing the content of the div.

Comment: I think toggleClass might work out a lot better, but you could also do http://jsfiddle.net/GvxgP/3/ to prevent the editing. That's more of a hack then a solution though.

Comment: Thanks again Joe but I have tried toggleClass and it doesn't work in this particular setup either.

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements don't support a focus state that I'm aware of, so you'll have to manually change the divs style anytime one of its inputs is focused (and of course change it back when the input is blurred).

```
$("div.line input").focus(function() {
    $(this).closest(".line").addClass("line-focus");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).closest(".line").removeClass("line-focus");
});
```

And of course change

```
.line:focus {  }
```

to

```
.line-focus {  }
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, however I cannot use CSS3 transitions using that method, and jQuery UI to animate the switching class does not allow for backgrounds using rgba();

Comment: @Delicious - who said anything about CSS3 transitions?  Maybe I don't understand.  The jQuery above will do what your original code was trying to do: change the style of a div when an input therein is focused.

Comment: @DeliciousMangos this is exactly what I was talking about. When you want to focus on the div., just use `.addClass()`

Comment: @Adam yes, but it will not allow me to transition between styles containing rgba(); in the background property.

Comment: JohnP, Adam, I cannot use addClass, removeClass, nor toggleClass because it does not allow the css style I have to animate/transition.

Comment: @Delicious - I think you might be out of luck then.  I don't think there's a way to apply a static css selector to a div that has some child input focused.  You might consider changing your style to something that can be animated with jQuery UI.

Comment: I was hoping to use css transitions originally anyway, and not jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".").focus()` only works on certain elements.
DIV isn't a supported element to be focused.

You can try to recreate focus using .click

```
 $("div").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('focused');
   if ($(this).hasClass('focused')){
      // do something
   }else{
      // do something else
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any other possible solutions to this?

Comment: I meant, are there any other options aside :focus or perhaps instead of using a div? (Though I really would like to use a div)

Comment: I cannot use toggleClass or add/removeClass as it doesn't allow for css3 transitions, and if I use jQuery UI to animate the transition, it does not let me use rgba() in my css styles.

Comment: The class toggling here is only to differ from "focused" state or "unfocused" state.
to add css3 transitions, add them in the // do something part

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
     $(this).css('background','green'); 
});
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VtEte/1/)